# Как сделать такой hover эффект?

Tags: html, css

[image: hover эффект]

Как сделать такой ховер эффект, что бы он плавно появлялся?

Comment: думаю, jquery animation подойдет. хотя вопрос не совсем понятен

Comment: Есть img, надо что бы при наведении появлялся вот этот синий блок с кнопками, надо что бы плавно появлялся.

Comment: Есть такие полезные штуки: http://api.jquery.com/         и       https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.b {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc url(http://via.placeholder.com/150x250) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.b-show {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s;
}

.b:hover .b-show {
  opacity: 1;
}

.b-show-content {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.b-show-content-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-container">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="b-show">
      <div class="b-show-content">
        <h2 class="b-show-content-title">Title</h2>
        <a class="btn">Btn</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```